# unable to migrate app to iphone5 retina 4

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I had migrated some apps to iPhone5 but with this one I am unable to solve it. I follow same steps but now I haven't got xib layout to set autosizing for window because TabBarViewController is programmatically defined as rootController. Always I am getting the annoying black front and top bars.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{    
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

    tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];

    NSArray *viewControllers = [NSArray alloc];

    viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: nil];

    // Attach them to the tab bar controller
    [self.tabBarController setViewControllers:viewControllers animated:NO];

    // Put the tabBarController's view on the window.
    [window addSubview:[self.tabBarController view]];

    self.window.rootViewController = self.tabBarController;

    [self.window makeKeyWindow];

    self.splashController = [[splashViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"splashViewController" bundle:nil aidioma:self.idioma];
    [self.window addSubview:[splashController view]];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

Comment: Did you add the appropriate 4 inch launch image which tells the app to run in 'fullscreen'?

Comment: You have a `Default-568h@2x.png` file in the bundle root?

Comment: thank you for your comments. That's right, I didn't know if no retina splash image is added when another ones are, no sizing will be applied. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To enable 4-inch display support, you need to add a file to the root of your project named **`Default-568h@2x.png`**.

So easy to figure out, right? :)

Comment: sure, I am always handling splash image using viewController but not for this app... so, no 4 inch retina splashImage when other resolution were added and retina sizing will not be applied anymore... mmm thank you very much, it works!